# Magnet interaction

Tags: electromagnetism

Can a permanent magnet be demagnetized from interacting with another permanent magnet? I know there are many ways of doing it but say i strap a bunch of magnets to two box fans and face them together, will they ever stop spinning?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not demagnetized, but you can change the orientation of its magnetization.

Basically, being magnetized is a low-energy state for a magnet. Let's say the initial magnetization of the magnet is along $\mathbf{\hat{z}}$. If you put this magnet into an external magnetic field that opposes the magnetization of the magnet, i.e. along $\mathbf{-\hat{z}}$ then you will make the energy of state with initial magnetization higher. Eventually, as you increase the applied field, you will make the energy of 'old magnetization' state higher than being not magnetized. At this point magnet will spontaneously demagnetize, but since the energy of being magnetized in the $-\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ will be even lower than no magnetization, the magnet will not stay demagnetized, but will simply switch to being magnetized in $-\mathbf{\hat{z}}$ - direction. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_hysteresis.

I have no idea what you mean about the fans though. You will need to explain it better.